# How to select rows that have a column that matches a value and fall between a date range using PHP's PDO and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can someone help me with my query below? I need to select all users who subscribe to the "Food Specials" newsletter (that has to be passed in through a form variable because there are different newsletter names) and have a value of "1" and that fall between the sign up dates that were selected in a form:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE :newsletter = 1 AND signed_up < ":start" AND signed_up < ":end"';
$result->bindValue(":newsletter", "food_specials", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(":start", "2012-09-01 12:00:00", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindValue(":end", "2012-09-25 12:00:00", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

First "food_specials" will never equal 1. You should probably bind a variable containing the value 1 here or something. Not sure what it's for. For the rest of this answer I'm going to assume `food_special` is the column name that you're trying to set with pdo. This cannot be done. What you need to do is just explicitly put it in the sql. See example below.

You also need to change

```
signed_up < ":start"
```

to

```
signed_up > :start
```

Ie what you need is

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
          FROM users 
         WHERE food_special = 1 
           AND signed_up > :start 
           AND signed_up < :end";
```

If by `signed_up > :start AND signed_up < :end` you actually meant `signed_up >= :start AND signed_up <= :end` then you should look @glavić's answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: I don't use PDO... but shouldn't PDO already escape string? Why do you have to add `"` or `'` around `:start` or `:end` ?

Comment: @glavić .. you're right, in the excitement of answering I got carried away :)

Comment: The only way I can seem to get this to work (with all three variables) is to bust out of the double quotes and add the var using $newsletter, $startDate, etc. Is this okay to do since I'm using PDO?

Comment: @Zoolander .. You should still bind the values like before. It should work fine. What are you trying that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE 
    :newsletter = 1 AND 
    signed_up BETWEEN :start AND :end
```